# Converting ffmpeg command to fluent-ffmpeg code

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, node.js

I need to write that command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://rtmp.global.cdn.vindral.com/publish/sk_b75a2aa5-9d18-4f44-8d38-cb33ac31c84b -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mp4 output.mp4
```

using fluent-ffmpeg. I wrote something like that, but it doesnt work:

```
const ffmpegStatic = require('ffmpeg-static');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegStatic);

ffmpeg()
  .input('rtmp://rtmp.global.cdn.vindral.com/publish/sk_b75a2aa5-9d18-4f44-8d38-cb33ac31c84b')
  .addOptions([
    '-vcodec', 'copy',
    '-acodec', 'copy',
    '-f', 'mp4'
  ])
  .output('output.mp4')
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I think it might be because of me using wrong options, i have no idea. Command itself works in terminal, but the code above doesnt even produce any error message.

Comment: I think `.run()` is missing at the end.